# Java array adding private return statement to Fibonnacci Sequence

Tags: java

I want to add the following line to my exiting code: `private int[] fibonacci(int n1, int n2, int length)` Still where n1 = 0, n2 = 1, length = 8. The result should produce an array similar to my code below.

```
public class MyProgram
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        new MyProgram().start();
    }

    public void start()
    {
        int[] arrNum = new int[8];
        arrNum[0] = 0;
        arrNum[1] = 1;

        for (int i = 2; i < arrNum.length; i++)
        {
            arrNum[i] = arrNum[i - 1] + arrNum[i - 2];              
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < arrNum.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(arrNum[i] + " ");
        }               
    }      
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Are you asking how to re-write your Fibonacci code so that it's recursive? Why?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're trying to do, you can change your program to something like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int[] arrNum = fibonacci(0, 1, 8);
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrNum));
}

private static int[] fibonacci(int n1, int n2, int length) {
  int[] arrNum = new int[length];
  arrNum[0] = n1;
  arrNum[1] = n2;
  for (int i = 2; i < arrNum.length; i++) {
    arrNum[i] = arrNum[i - 1] + arrNum[i - 2];
  }
  return arrNum;
}
```

And I get the expected output of

```
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]
```